# how to programmatically set or reset checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox

Purpose: when a particular checkbox is checked or unchecked, the program must change a number of other checkboxes according to programmed rules.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" (change)="onChangeChk($event)">Test Checkbox

  onChangeChk($event) {
    $event.srcElement.value = "on"; // or "off"
  }
```

The checkbox remains in its original state no matter how the onChangeChk sets it.

Thanks for you help on this.
:-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can assign the `checked` property of your input element to true or false.

Like so:

```
onChangeChk($event) {
    $event.srcElement.checked = true; // or false
}
```

See also here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Comment: LOL ... thanks, I JUST found that out myself.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Worked for me for unchecking checkbox progrmmatically $event.source.checked=false;

Answer (score 6):

If you have a *CheckBox*:

```
<mat-checkbox
  [checked]="filterStatusPrivatUser"
  #privatUserCheckbox>Privat User</mat-checkbox>
```

You can access the *checked* attribute using *ViewChild* like so:

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

filterStatusPrivatUser: boolean = true;

@ViewChild('privatUserCheckbox') privatUserCheckbox: ElementRef;
```

And then change the value programatically like so:

```
changeCheckboxProgramatically() {
    this.privatUserCheckbox['checked'] = true;
}
```