# (change) event is not firing if you change [checked] value programmatically angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have below HTML table body. In one column I have a checkbox, when I am changing [checked] value programmatically. (change) event is not firing?

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of Results" [ngClass]="selectClass(item)">
            <td>
                <mat-checkbox
                    type="checkbox"
                    [checked]="isSelected"
                    (change)="onCheck($event, item)"
                ></mat-checkbox>
            </td>
            <td>{{ item.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Id}}</td>
        </tr></tbody>
```

Comment: instead of `[checked]="isSelected"` try `[(ngModel)]="isSelected"`

Comment: @JasonWhite tried with [(ngModel)]="isSelected" but no result.

Comment: Make sure you import the `FormsModule` in the module declaring the component

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your view has no idea that you changed the value programmatically. It could even happen that you get an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. You can use the changeDetectorRef to detect the changes manually:

```
constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef){
}

select(newValue: boolean): void {
  this.isSelected = newValue;
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: tried with same 'ChangeDetectorRef' but the result makes no difference for me.

Comment: Then potentially, you can not set the value of a mat checkbox programmatically like this and would have to use a ViewChild. See here how this problem was solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699783/how-to-programmatically-set-or-reset-checkbox (not set as duplicate as I mean the not accepted, other solution)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following:

View:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of Results" [ngClass]="selectClass(item)">
        <td>
            <mat-checkbox
                #myCheckbox
                type="checkbox"
                (change)="onCheck($event, item)"
            ></mat-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>{{ item.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.Id}}</td>
    </tr></tbody>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChildren('myCheckbox') myCheckbox: QueryList<MatCheckbox>;
```

...Method that updates checkbox

```
myMethod(): void {
for (const checkbox of this.myCheckbox.toArray()) {
  checkbox.checked = true;

  const myEvent: MatCheckboxChange = {
    checked: true,
    source: checkbox,
  };

  checkbox.change.emit(myEvent);
}
}
```

This should trigger the (change) event in the view for each checkbox in the loop.